# Why is my ui-router state doesn't work?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I cannot figure out why my state works first time only from the index but not in the appcontainer:

```
$locationProvider.hashPrefix('!').html5Mode({
            enabled: true,
            requireBase: false
        });

        $stateProvider
        .state('app', {
            abstract: true,
            url: '',
            templateUrl: 'appcontainer.html'
        })
        .state('app.stateAAA', {
            url: 'aaa',
            templateUrl: 'aaa.html'
        })
        .state('app.stateBBB', {
            url: 'bbb',
            templateUrl: 'bbb.html'
        })
        .state('app.stateCCC', {
            url: 'ccc',
            templateUrl: 'ccc.html'
        });
```

appconteiner:

```
<ul>
  <li><a ui-sref="app.stateAAA">aaa</a></li>
  <li><a ui-sref="app.stateBBB">bbb</a></li>
  <li><a ui-sref="app.stateCCC">ccc</a></li>
</ul>

<ui-view></ui-view>
```

Have look on [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/wyQfHRtwbhEBx9qSqa9x?p=preview)

Comment: can u share appcontainer.html

Comment: @Whistler why you have url's without slash `/`, that would be horrible in real application

Comment: with slashes doesnt work at all

Comment: if I add slashes and remove hasPrefix and html5Mode it works, but I want to keep that for clean url